# Error deploying database in VS 2008 w/ SQL Server 2005 size must be at least 3MB?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm getting the following error deploying my database in VS 2008 with a local SQL Server 2005. I deployed other databases, but this one seems to fail.

> Bsg.COC.Database.dbschema(0,0)Error
>   TSD01268: .Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider: Msg 1803, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 The CREATE DATABASE statement
>   failed. The primary file must be at
>   least 3 MB to accommodate a copy of
>   the model database.

I did some searching and some suggestions were to disable the size attribute, but I was unable to find where to change this setting in the IDE, only in the outputted SQL query. Do you know where to find the size attribute setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it, in the Database\Schema Objects\Database Level Objects\Storage\Files\DATABASENAME.sqlfile.sql file, the setting is "size=??", if you just change that to a lower number it will deploy just fine.

Comment: Thinks for the info, well it only took you 10 minutes to find without this post, good work!!!